# How to create a responsive products list view?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a responsive list view in CSS from scratch.

However, the issue that I have is that the green button doesn't sit where it should be.

It doesn't sit next to the image and under the text.

Also, when I re-size my screen to smaller size, the layout of the list gets messed up but I need it to look (more or less) to be similar on every screen size.

This is what I have so far:

```css
.contentHolder {
  width: 90%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.contentHolder p {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}

.txtHolder {
  width: 65%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-left: 10px;
  max-height: 120px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

.p_img {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url(https://cloud.netlifyusercontent.com/assets/344dbf88-fdf9-42bb-adb4-46f01eedd629/68dd54ca-60cf-4ef7-898b-26d7cbe48ec7/10-dithering-opt.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.cartBtn {
  width: 200px;
  line-height: 20px;
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contentHolder">

  <div class="p_img"></div>

  <div class="txtHolder">
    <p>Hello wordl, this is some dummy text that goes here very nicely and tidy... Enjoy reading me when you can...Hello wordl, this is some dummy text that goes here very nicely and tidy... Enjoy reading me when you can...Hello wordl, this is some dummy
      text that goes here very nicely and tidy... Enjoy reading me when you can...</p>
  </div>

  <div class="cartBtn">
    Add to cart
  </div>

</div>
```

Can anyone please advice on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to get all the divs in another div (It might help with formatting the button)

For example:

```
<div class="item">
<div class="img"></div>
<div class="itmDesc">
Hi I am text how are you?
</div>
<div class="cartBtn">
Add to cart
</div>
</div>
```

This might help (if not, then I am sorry)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to accomdate all screen sizes (viewports) than you actually need to identify the viewport properties and accordingly apply different CSS adjustments. There simply isn't really a one size fits all solution. (Welcome to wonderful world of smartphones haha).

However, try to identify what is the most likely tech your users are going to access your system with, and work with that first. Going full on cross-platform cross-device is a lot of work so don't be discouraged, it's a lot to ask from one person, and will take time if you want or required to do so.

As for the button - it's currently stuck in the same container with the image and the text. just pull it out of that:

```
<div class="contentHolder">

<div class="p_img"></div>

<div class="txtHolder">
<p>Hello wordl, this is some dummy text that goes here very nicely and tidy... Enjoy reading me when you can...Hello wordl, this is some dummy text that goes here very nicely and tidy... Enjoy reading me when you can...Hello wordl, this is some dummy text that goes here very nicely and tidy... Enjoy reading me when you can...</p>
</div>

</div>

<div class="cartBtn">
Add to cart
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `.p_img { height:100%;`. Now you don't need it (you could solve it other), but let's stick with that. So what you need to do is you need to `float` the image. Floating ain't such a nice thing but works nicely if you don't forget to clear floats. Check the comments in code.

```css
.contentHolder{
  width:90%;
  height:200px;
  background-color:#fff;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  padding:10px;
  border-radius:5px;
}

/* add this block, this will clear the float! */
.contentHolder:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

.contentHolder p{
  width:100%;
  padding-left:10px;
  margin:0;
}

.txtHolder{
  width:65%;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  padding-left:10px;
  max-height:120px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  margin:0;
}

.p_img{
  width:30%;
  height:100%;
  display:inline-block;
  background-image:url(https://cloud.netlifyusercontent.com/assets/344dbf88-fdf9-42bb-adb4-46f01eedd629/68dd54ca-60cf-4ef7-898b-26d7cbe48ec7/10-dithering-opt.jpg);
  background-size:cover; 
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center center;
  border-radius:5px;
  vertical-align:top;
  
  float: left; /* add this line */
}

.cartBtn{
  width:200px;
  line-height:20px;
  background:green;
  color:#fff;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  float:left;
  padding:10px;
  text-align:center;
  border-radius:5px;
  
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px; /* add this line */
}
```

```html
<div class="contentHolder">

<div class="p_img"></div>

<div class="txtHolder">
<p>Hello wordl, this is some dummy text that goes here very nicely and tidy... Enjoy reading me when you can...Hello wordl, this is some dummy text that goes here very nicely and tidy... Enjoy reading me when you can...Hello wordl, this is some dummy text that goes here very nicely and tidy... Enjoy reading me when you can...</p>
</div>

<div class="cartBtn">
Add to cart
</div>

</div>
```